# Send a signal of 1-2V for a second while circuit is on all the time

Tags: arduino, signal, button

I have a circuit that needs a signal for a second to turn on. The signal is a 1-2 volt for a period of 1-2 second.

So when the main switch is powered on it needs to send the signal or conduct electricity for a secondary circuit for a second to say it is turned on.

Or in other assumptions, I have a tactile button. When I press it for once it sends a signal to another circuit that needs the signal of this tactile button. I want to replace the tactile button with a transistor or with something when power is on for all the time but it sends only one-time high signal. Like it should work as a tactile button for once. just to send a signal for only once while for the whole time the main power becomes on.

Comment: Buttons don't send voltage signals, they *connect* existing sources.  Unless you want to use something pretty isolated like a relay, you're going to need to provide more detail of the circuit to be controlled.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, Yes it will connect the existing source of power just for a second. but while power is on it will keep connecting the voltage. So I want it to connect the existing source just for a second and then cut it off.

Comment: This is pretty confusing. See if you can draw both a circuit diagram and a timing diagram - what stays on when?

Comment: You need to supply details of how the switch is wired in *that* circuit.  Or else use something that is simply a controlled switch, like a relay.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, ok, with your solution the relay will be kept on all the time if the main power is on or if the signal is high all the time. I want the relay to work only for 1 second. Is there a solution that turns on the relay for a second, but while the signal is high for the relay all the time?

Comment: @Reinderien, Think of two circuits. When one became on then the second circuit will become on for a second. when the first circuit is off so second is off all the time. When again the first circuit powered on the second circuit will come on for a second and turns off. Or in another example, I want an Led to be one for a second when the circuit powers on.

Comment: Of course not!  The relay would only be on when your controller turns it on for the brief period desired.  But a relay is a poor solution.  **You must provide details of the circuit to be controlled** so that a better solution can be suggested.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I have an LED. When the 5V power is connected so it should just blink for a second. The problem is that the led remains constantly ON when it gets the power.

I want to get a blink on the LED when a 5V power is connected. I tried to use a combination of transistors but the LED will keep itself on and or and or keep blinking. So the main point is when power is off LED is off. When power is on LED will be on for a second.

Comment: That bears almost no relation to the question on this page, but since you tagged this Arduino, write your Arduino *software* to only activate the LED briefly.  Otherwise, *edit* your question to remove the Arduino tag, and also make your question meaningfully reflect your goal, whatever that *really* is.

Comment: I think he wants a POR Power on Reset signal, which is normally negative logic or low=0 = asserted as the power voltage rises for some period of xx ms to tell the CPU and logic to initialize.  Often this is just a Cap and high value pull-up resistor into a Schmitt trigger or integrated into some other device.

Comment: So you have a device with a button that needs to be pressed to turn it on, but you want it to turn on automatically when power is applied, correct? What is the device?

Answer (score 2):

If this is what you want:

a) press a button for 1/2 second, and the circuit makes an output for 1 second

and

b) press a button for 2 seconds, and the circuit makes an output for 1 second

Then:

The circuit you want is called a monostable, short for monostable multivibrator.  There are several variations, but only one of them will work for you.  A true monostable has positive feedback that makes the output completely independent of anything happening at the input after it is triggered.

The circuit details depend on the power source available and the amount of output current you need.  But a basic monostable circuit that makes an output of 1-2 V is pretty simple.  2 transistors, or 2 logic gates (plus some resistors and capacitors).

Answer (score 0):

Let's make a guess so wild as to be functionally meaningless:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKYREW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The output will go on immediately when the button is pressed, and C1 will charge fully. When the button is released, C1 will discharge through R3, and after about 1s will be at 50% of 5V, so the comparator output will go low and the LED will go off.

Comment: BUT - if the button hs held down continuously, the output is high continuously.  this is not what is requested in comment #2.

Comment: @AnalogKid that's why I asked for a timing diagram..

Comment: @Reinderien, the button is held down continuously, so the D1 led will receive power for a 1 second. it will happen each time SW1 is pressed/released and or held down.

Answer (score -1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fibaQp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>